# How to add to two images in one figure on each other with different colormaps in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In some cases, especially in scientific papers, authors add two images in one figure on each other with different colormaps. you can see an example in the below images. Can anyone guide me on how to use matplotlib to create these kinds of images?

[image: image of plot showing time since ignition in orange and elevation in grey]

Comment: If you use pcolormesh, the regions marked nan will be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one plot area and then simply add lines graphs, barcharts, etc. etc. to the same plot area. For example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))

ax.plot(df_1.index, df_1['Column_Name'], linewidth=5, color='blue', label='Some_Label')
ax.legend(loc='upper right')
ax.plot(df_2.index, df_2['Column_Name'], label='Some_Label')
ax.legend(loc='upper right')
```

You can create graphs using matplotlib, pandas or seaborn - it just depends what you are looking to create. What I did above is create 2 line graphs on the same plotting area - but you can do the same with other types of graphs.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I mean how to add two images, not a graph. Adding to a graph in a figure is easy. I paste an example image you can check it.